# Retrieving data via sftp with NMSSH in Swift

Tags: swift, ftp, sftp, nmssh

I am trying to get a JSON file from my server to my iPhone. I am using NMSSH for my FTP connection and the connection works.

But I can't retrieve any data from my server. It doesn't matter what path I am using `~/` or `/` or `/someFolder/` or `someFolder`. Every time, I am getting the error:

> NMSSH_Test[] NMSSH: Could not open file at path /testDirectory (Error 0: )

Here my code:

```swift
class Data {
    init() {
        let session = NMSSHSession.init(host: "someIp", andUsername: "user")
        session.connect()
        if session.isConnected{
            session.authenticate(byPassword: "password")
            if session.isAuthorized {
                let sftpsession = NMSFTP(session : session)
                sftpsession.contents(atPath: "/testDirectory")
//                if (sftpsession.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "~/") != nil) {
//                    print("Found Data!")
//                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: connection works without problems. I can also send data to my server.

Comment: What about checking the error conditions on an `else` branch of each if ?

Comment: Found the solution. I also have to use .connect() for the sftpsession variable that I created. So I have to use it twice if im correct. It works!

Comment: If you made it work, would you mind posting an answer with a couple of explanations, so that people who have the same problem can solve it as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
let session = NMSSHSession(host: serverHost, port: portNo, andUsername: serverUsername)
session.connect()
if session.isConnected{
         let privateKeypath:String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mykey", ofType: "")!
         let privateKey: String = try! String(contentsOfFile: privateKeypath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                
         session.authenticateBy(inMemoryPublicKey: "", privateKey: privateKey, andPassword: passwordStr)
                
         if session.isAuthorized == true {
                let sftpsession = NMSFTP(session: session)
                sftpsession.connect()
                if sftpsession.isConnected {
                     print("download session is connected")
                }
                else {
                     print("Error: download session not connected")
                return
                }
                guard let directoryContents = downloadSession.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "Your Directory Path goes here!")
                else {
                     print("Unable to read contents of file in SSH site")
                return
                }
                print("Data at specified path captured: " + directoryContents)
                 
                guard let contentList = downloadSession.contents(atPath:  "Enter your path here!")
                else {
                     print("Unable to read contents of file in SSH site")
                return
                }
                print("Printing Contents of file at path")
                print(contentList)             
                }
            }
       }
```

Comment: I have been trying to get a file from remote SFTS server to I-phone for two years now. I read several articles in this site as well as in GITHUB and other areas. I keep getting the error unable to open file at remote location. I have checked read/write permissions in the location and there are no issues. I can get a list of files in the directory, but not get a file from SFTS using contents(atPAth: ). Please see my code below. Any help is apprecated

Comment: Can you share your code?